# Issue with installing postnuke

Tags: zikula

I need an old copy of the software Postnuke. I’m aware it’s outdated and discontinued but need to use it locally to use & convert a site which used to use this software.

I managed to find it using SourceForge (the 0.76 version) but it keeps hanging on the installation and I’m getting errors that don’t seem fixable to me on the step of inserting data (around 80%).

If any of the devs are around I’d really appreciate any assistance they could give me on how to get the “Set Login” stage working of the installer, specifically the start_postnuke() function because it’s missing the language and other variables from the PNconfig variable that are preventing it from installing.

I’m aware this is tagged as a Zikula question but it’s the only way I can find to try and contact who I assume are the developers of Postnuke.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Postnuke is dead. It died so long ago that nobody has any expertise. I doubt very much that installing the software is possible or truly necessary. You must have a database with info you are trying to access. Simply access it with whatever tools you are most comfortable with and pull and modify the data as needed. (fyi - I'm a former postnuke dev and current zikula dev. I've used PN since 0.62, so I know what I'm talking about).

Comment: I’m not just converting the data but also a postnuke theme as well, which is why I needed to get it working. That’s not to mention the phpBB module. Saying that it can’t be done and just closing down all options available really isn’t helpful.

Comment: installing and viewing the theme also will not help. The theme is standard html with `<!--[ ]-->` tags within where the injected content will go. If you are converting to Zikula or some other CMS then you would create something similar. Any hardcoded content within can just be copy/paste with any text editor. the phpBB module probably won't work either (if you can find it). but you might be able to transcode it to a working phpBB  'straight' install. Downvoting my answer because you don't _like_ it doesn't help either. I gave you an actual working solution. Rob's answer may help also.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer because I didn't like it. I downvoted it because you basically dismissed my question without even explaining anything and your reply didn't help me. That said, it's the forum which I really need. But I do need the PN theme BlackDog for the phpBB module. I actually have found it but I'm not sure about the relationship between themes and the phpBB module. The reason I wanted a working installation was so I can see changes to make sure everything is working as it should- I've never used this software before and the website is no longer active which I'm porting over.

Comment: The actual data isn't a problem, if I'd just wanted the data I'd already have at least tried to just do a database restore. It would save a lot of time. It's only because I needed to port the style that I wanted a working installation, so that I can make sure all pages have gone across and make sure everything still would look the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to give it a go on getting a working installation I would recommend using the same server stack components that were "modern" at the time 0.76 was released.  Apache, php, mysql.  It will probably work then.

Since that time a lot of php functions have been made obsolete, and even syntax changed such as array shorthand notation.

But if you use a stack that's contemporary to that version, it should work.